# Can you duplicate Edge Loops to another part of an object?

Tags: mesh, objects, edit-mode

I have created a design for a HDMI port (circled in red), and I want to copy the design/edge loops to the right of it. Is it possible to do this via any method?.

Thankyou in advance, its to be apart of a ASUS VG27AQ monitor for my first solo project.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou @common_goldfish. Your comment combined with some feedback from someone else helped a lot.

I didn’t follow exactly as you showed, but what you did gave my memory a good nudge as to how I could go about this.

1. Copying the vertices of the HDMI port and then using the "snap to
   edge" function to keep the "New" HDMI port vertices in-line with the
   first one worked well.
2. As my object is not symmetrical I just copied the vertices of the
   HMDI port and not the entirety of the vertical loop cuts
   (Duplicating the entirety of the loop cuts and then moving them
   meant they were left dangling in the air),
3. I added loop cuts in afterwards, using "snap to vertex"
   to align them to the relevant places.
4. I then used "Merge vertices by distance" to remove the doubles. (I
   wanted to ensure I had the loops cuts as it kept all of the faces as
   quads.)

Comment: Cool you found a solution with snap to edges and some new loop cuts.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

You can create reusable patches with both faces and vertices.

1.It is a neater operation if you create an empty rectangular face where you can copy your vertices.

2.Turn on vertices snapping

3.In edit mode, select faces and vertices, and duplicate a patch of your geometry with  **shift+d**

4. Press Y or other axis, to snap and move the patch over to the empty space in the geometry where you want to copy.

5.Snap the corner vertices, and then **press M** **merge them by distance**.

6.Optionally you can make a duplicate,  select the hole patch and **press P** and then save the selection for later use.

[image]

[image]

[image]